# Artifactory 5.11 on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, artifactory

I'm trying to install Artifactory 5.11 on Windows 10 by using the provided artifactory.bat running as Administrator. I set the JAVA_HOME and the ARTIFACTORY_HOME system variables according to the system.
Installation fails because of errors with tomcat-juli and javax/xml/bin/JAXBException which cannot be found.

The auto-wiring of the field org.artifactory.api.security.UserGroupService, org.artifactory.security.access.AccessService and org.artifactory.api.repo.RepositoryService failed.

Derby and Tomcat are used from the distribution. I'm using Java 10.0.1.

Should this combination work? Could the installation failure come from user privilege settings on Windows?

Thanks for your support.

Regards,
Claus

Comment: Please add some code so other users can test what you're describing. Thanks!

Comment: There is no custom code. I downloaded Artifactory 5.11 and tried to install it as described here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lg4a6Sc_Xco

I just deleted everything and redone it. The errors remain...

The occuring errors from the install log are described in the first entry.

Answer (score 0):

From Artifactory WIKI page:

JDK
You must run Artifactory with JDK 8, preferably JDK 8 update 45 and above.

**Please try using JAVA 8**

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/System+Requirements

Comment: It worked going back to Java8. I wonder, why this doesn't work with Java 10, as in the past newer versions of Java normally were able to run older code.
Thanks a lot!